# Can I prevent the Android Studio build speed from getting slower?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I don't want to know how to speed up my Android Studio (1.1) build time in general.

Actually it's okay but only until the first 〜10 builds to an Android device/emulator. Then I usually restart Android Studio and the build speed is fine again. I just can't believe this what it should be.

For my current app I measured a build time of around **28 seconds** for the first 10 runs and then for the 11th I measured 39 seconds and for the 12th **3 minutes and 16 seconds**.

How can it be that it is getting this much slower and is there a possibility to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

there are some tricks to improve your Android Studio performance:

- Activate gradle deamon: https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/
- Activate Compiler features: *Settings -> Compiler*, then activate "Compiler independent...", "Use in-process build" and "Configuration on demand".

With these two tricks you'll feel the difference. Let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but I already did those optimizations. They didn't stop the build speed from getting slower after around 10 builds though.

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio 
Go to > File > Settings > in Build Go to > Compiler
and add the content in VM Options: --Xmx2048 --XX:MazPermSize=512m
and in Command-line Options: --offline

this think build your project with in a second